# Angular SwUpdate activated deprecation

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, deprecated, angular-service-worker

In my angular project I have this kind of code:

```
this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
  ...
});
```

It work fine but gives me the warning about `activated` being deprecated.

What should I do to fix this warning?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe `activated` and `activateUpdate()` are different things.  You call `activateUpdate()`, then when it's done, `activated` happens.

Furthermore, `activated` and `available` are definitely different things (your question references both).  `available` means an update is detected; `activated` means it's been installed.

According to the docs (https://angular.io/api/service-worker/SwUpdate), the replacement for `available` is:

```
import {filter, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
// ...
const updatesAvailable = swUpdate.versionUpdates.pipe(
  filter((evt): evt is VersionReadyEvent => evt.type === 'VERSION_READY'),
  map(evt => ({
    type: 'UPDATE_AVAILABLE',
    current: evt.currentVersion,
    available: evt.latestVersion,
  })));
```

Comment: How can I check more frequently? It feels like it checks like every 20 minutes. I want to check every minute

Comment: Do swUpdate.checkForUpdate() every minute.

Answer (score 5):

You must change `activated` to `activateUpdate()` and treat it as `Promise`:

```
this.swUpdate.activateUpdate().then(() => {
 ...
});
```